# Argument 2 passed to Monolog\Logger::__construct() must be of the type array, string given

Tags: php, logging, symfony

I'm having an issue that is breaking my mind!
I am developing an app for fun to do rankings.. and I'm receiving this error in every @URL

> Type error: Argument 2 passed to Monolog\Logger::__construct() must be of the type array, string given, called in /var/www/votacioneslol/votacionesLol/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 2021

If I go to this line:

```
/**
     * Gets the 'logger' service.
     *
     * This service is shared.
     * This method always returns the same instance of the service.
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger A Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger instance
     */
    protected function getLoggerService()
    {
        //this line
        $this->services['logger'] = $instance = new \Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger('', 'app');

        $instance->pushProcessor(${($_ = isset($this->services['debug.log_processor']) ? $this->services['debug.log_processor'] : $this->getDebug_LogProcessorService()) && false ?: '_'});
        $instance->useMicrosecondTimestamps(true);
        $instance->pushHandler($this->get('monolog.handler.console'));
        $instance->pushHandler($this->get('monolog.handler.main'));

        return $instance;
    }
```

I thought it would be a session problem but.. After enable UserFOSBundle I tested it and it worked well (login and signup) so I started to develop a custom form and some things more. When I wanted to test the basic forms (create) I found this error.

**Any idea? There is no help on internet or I Haven't found it!**

**Ask for code if you need more things!**

**Thank you at all!**

Comment: related: [logger error Argument 2 passed to Monolog\Logger::__construct() must be array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40843313), [`[BUG][DependencyInjection] Logger service has a construct error since #10619 #10626`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10626)

Comment: raelly thnk you! It worked for me!

Comment: @greybeard Anyway, it just permits to the url's works.. because I still cannot cache:clear or install assetics.. :( BTW, I have the src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php like in the post.. and doesn't work, I don't know why the file(appDevDebugProjectContainer.php) always has the 2 parameters when I use the require assetic or cache:clear...